# Migrate only orders in magento 2 from Magento 1.9 using mysqlworkbench

Tags: magento2, migration

I mapped **sales_flat_order** table of magento 1.9 to **sales_order** table of magento 2 and push the csv from mysqlworkbench. and orders was migrated in the database. The orders are even displaying in the frontend.

The products and customer data migration was done before this. Is there any problem in this migration... Anyone have gone through the same order migration process ?

Comment: Any reason why you don't use the official migration tool : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate.html ?

Comment: Because Magento Migration tool is for complete migration process. But I have already migrated customer data and now I only have to migrate the orders. Is it possible to migrate only the orders by magento migration tool ?

Comment: can u please advise https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292904/magento-2-reorder-functionality-missing-for-migrated-orders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we should map some more tables:

```
Magento 1                     || Magento 2
sales_flat_order                 sales_order
sales_flat_order_address         sales_order_address
sales_flat_order_grid            sales_order_grid
sales_flat_order_item            sales_order_item
sales_flat_order_payment         sales_order_payment
sales_flat_order_status_history  sales_order_status_history
```

If we had the invoices and shipments, we need to map more tables.

*Note:* when we want to clear the order from Magento 2, we can use [this module](https://github.com/ibnab/magento2-delete-orders).

Comment: can u advise https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292904/magento-2-reorder-functionality-missing-for-migrated-orders